# Scikit learn categorical features ranking

Tags: python, r, numpy, scikit-learn

My data contained a lot of categorical data, for example, Age, color, size, race, gender and so on.
The problem is that in scikit-learn we could not set the features as a factor as in R, therefore we have to convert the categorical data in to the dummy column. As

```
color size
green  M
red    L
blue   XL
```

convert to

```
color_blue  color_green  color_red  size_L  size_M  size_XL
0.0          1.0        0.0         0.0     1.0      0.0
0.0          0.0        1.0         1.0     0.0      0.0
1.0          0.0        0.0         0.0     0.0      1.0
```

However, I would like to rank the features as the color or size, not color_blue or size_M.
Is there any possible ways to do it? or I can summarize the value from the ranking score from each related feature? 
(like score for color column should be sum of (green blue and red scores))

Note that I use ExtraTreesClassifier for the ranking score calculation.

Comment: What do you mean by "rank the features"?

Comment: Hi Brenbarn, Ranking the features is that when you have 50 features in your dataset but you want to eliminate some features before training. For example, chi-square testing checks the null hypothesis is true or not. Sorry, I am also new for machine learning so I may not use the correct words. Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you looked at the [feature selection module](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html)? You should also consider editing your question to provide a minimal working example, because it is still not very clear what exactly you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, what you want is to be able to sort the columns by the values on them. Maybe try [OrdinalEncoder()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html)? that takes the column and assigns a number in a learnt order (or you can pass it a list with the order you want).